# Socket recieves Images with delay of 1

Tags: android, sockets, stream, bufferedimage

I have a socket that recieves images via one InputStream that doesnt get closed. I want to send images continiously that way. But now the images get recieved with a delay of 1 image (the first one after I sent the second one, the second one after I sent the third one, ....). What am I doing wrong?

## Server

```
  public static void readImages(InputStream stream) throws IOException    {
     stream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
     BufferedImage image = null;
     int j = 0;

     while (true) {

        stream.mark(MAX_IMAGE_SIZE);

        ImageInputStream imgStream =  ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream);
        Iterator<ImageReader> i = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imgStream);
        if (!i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("No more image readers");
            break;
        }

        ImageReader reader = i.next();
        reader.setInput(imgStream);

        image = reader.read(0);
        ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",new File("current" + j + ".jpg"));
        System.out.println("Save an image " + j);


        if (image == null) {
            System.out.println("Image is null");
            break;
        }

        long bytesRead = imgStream.getStreamPosition();

        stream.reset();
        stream.skip(bytesRead);
        j++;
    }
}
```

## Client

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    OutputStream outputStream = server.getOutputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmapToSend =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToSend, 900, 800, true);
                    bitmapToSend.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,  100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    outputStream.write(byteArray);
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Socket not created");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Note I dont close the output stream of the client, so I can send pictures all the time.

Comment: What code do you use to send a second or third picture?

Comment: I take a picture (bufferedImage) with the camera and assign it to bitmapToSend. The rest is the "Client" snippet

Comment: yeah, that´s already implemented in cyanide´s answer, but there´s a problem. I put it in a comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ImageIO.getImageReaders(imgStream) doesn't seem logical for socket streams, since it probably expects all images to be available at once. That may be the reason of your delay.

Secondly, for decompressing images there is a simple method BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

Thirdly, since client already creates a "JPG" format, the server just needs to store it. You only need to send at start the number of bytes and zero  after all files have been sent.

Client:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream memoryStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bitmapToSend =
                    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToSend, 900, 800, true);
                bitmapToSend.compress(
                     Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, memoryStream);
                byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.toByteArray();
                memoryStream = null;

                DataOutputStream outputStream = 
                          new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeInt(byteArray.length);
                outputStream.write(byteArray);
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Socket not created");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Server:

```
public static void readImages(InputStream stream) {

    DataInputStream imgInput = new DataInputStream(stream);
    int index = 0;
    int byteLength;

    try {
        while ((byteLength = imgInput.readInt())>0) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[byteLength];
            imgInput.readFully(buffer);

            OutputStream imgOutput = new FileOutputStream("current" + (index++) + ".jpg");
            imgOutput.write(buffer);
            imgOutput.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // .............
    } finally {
        try {
            imgInput.close();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            //...........
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I inserted the methods into my code, but now it sends the first image and stops there. The image is only filled with "valid" pixels in the two top rows, the rest is just grey. Could that be a problem with the 'imgInput.readInt()' ?

Comment: so the Image repeats the last valid pixel of the second row. When I just print the Image via ImageIO, I get the full image. So I think it has to do with saving the inside of the while loop

Comment: `imgInput.read(buffer)` should probably be `imgInput.readFully(buffer)` (or you could implement some "smarter" read/write loop that uses a smaller buffer). In any case, don't rely on `imgInput.read(buffer)` to completely fill the buffer.